# PowerApps Distance Between Coordinates in a Loop

Tags: loops, sharepoint, powerapps, forall

I am new to PowerApps. I have a Share Point List with a set of coordinates for various locations. What I need to figure out is when a user with PowerApps App on their phone are within a certain distance of those coordinates, using the Haversine formula. While the Haversine formula works in a test/simple way using hard-coded target location, I need the target locations from the Share Point List. Here is my code, which is inside a Timer End:

```
ForAll(
  irfan_yard_locations,
 With(
    {
        r: 6371000,  p: (Pi() / 180),  latA: location_lat,  lonA: location_long, latB: Location.Latitude,  lonB: Location.Longitude
    },
    Round((2 * r) * Asin(Sqrt(0.5 - Cos((latA - latB) * p)/2 + Cos(latB * p) * Cos(latA * p) * (1 - Cos((lonA - lonB) * p)) / 2)), 2 ));
) ;
```

`irfan_yard_locations` is the SP List which has `location_lat` and `location_long` coordinates. I am thinking something like in this example site: http://powerappsguide.com/blog/post/formula-how-to-use-the-if-and-switch-functions so that if the return from the `with ()`, which would be a number, is less than 5 (it's in meters) then Navigate to another screen or do something. Just don't know the syntax. Or is there better approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. By putting in an `If` clause around the `With` function, I am able to catch if the  current location is within 6 meters of one of the coordinate sets.

```
ForAll(
  irfan_yard_locations,
If ( With(
    {
        r: 6371000,  p: (Pi() / 180),  latA: location_lat,  lonA: location_long, latB: Location.Latitude,  lonB: Location.Longitude
    },
    Round((2 * r) * Asin(Sqrt(0.5 - Cos((latA - latB) * p)/2 + Cos(latB * p) * Cos(latA * p) * (1 - Cos((lonA - lonB) * p)) / 2)), 2 )) < 6, Navigate(Screen2));
) ;
```